# Sender Account not Recognized

Tags: solidity, contract-development, erc-20, openzeppelin

I am trying to take the following test.

I have my smart contract COINERC20, when I instantiated I am mining for different portfolios, eg an X value for portfolio for ICO Private.

In my tests via Truffle, what do I need to do:

- Transfer my tokens from Private wallet to Smart Contract SALES (this contract will be used to sell the coins at ICO).
  But I'm having the following error:

```
Error: Returned error: sender account not recognized
```

Below I'm putting my test file, I'm not putting my ERC20 contract because it's the default Openzeppelin template.

The solidity version I'm using "0.8.0"

```
const { expect } = require('chai');

const SALES = artifacts.require('SALES');
const COINERC20 = artifacts.require('COINERC20');

contract("SALES", (accounts) => {

    const accountPrivateSales = "0xf452611E6066C881A83610e3b4656b3B593f7AD1";
    const amountPrivateSales = "10000000";
    let coinInstance, contractInstance;

    beforeEach(async () => {       
        coinInstance = await COINERC20.new();
        contractInstance = await SALES.new(coinInstance.address);        
    });

    describe("Validate pre-sales from account privateSales", async () => {
        it(`Verifiy amount in accountPrivateSales to be equal ${amountPrivateSales}`, async () => {
            let total  = await coinInstance.balanceOf(accountPrivateSales);
           
            expect(web3.utils.fromWei(total)).to.be.equal(amountPrivateSales);
        });
        it(`Verifiy amount in smart contract SALES to be equal 0`, async () => {
            let total  = await coinInstance.balanceOf(contractInstance.address);
           
            expect(web3.utils.fromWei(total)).to.be.equal("0");
        });
        it(`Transfer accountPrivate to smart contract SALES`, async () => {
            coinInstance = await COINERC20.deployed(accountPrivateSales);
            let total  = await coinInstance.balanceOf(accountPrivateSales);
            await coinInstance.approve(contractInstance.address, total, {from: accountPrivateSales});
            await coinInstance.transferFrom(accountPrivateSales, contractInstance.address, total, {from: accountPrivateSales})

             total  = await coinInstance.balanceOf(contractInstance.address);
            console.log("TOTALL === "+total)
        });
    });
})
```

Comment: Did you add the accountPrivateSales address to ganache ? It seems like you did not. You code throws an error on `await coinInstance.approve(contractInstance.address, total, {from: accountPrivateSales});`
 right ?

Comment: How do I add the account to ganache? can you tell? I'm using the account I made in metamask.

Comment: You could use this syntax to start ganache-cli with a custom account : `$ ganache-cli --account privateKey,balanceInWei` but to be fair, the best is just that you use one of the provided accounts for your tests like accounts[X]. Using a real private key in a test environment is a security risk anyway. If you can just set accountPrivateSales to one of the ganache provided accounts, it will be simpler and will not risk exposing any sensitive data.